# Docusign is sending document twice within email?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

i'm currently testing the docusign signature API and i'm having issues with creating an envelope from template. The email sends my document twice, repeated and i can't seem to fix it without screwing something else up.

```js
{
  "status":"sent",
  "emailBlurb":"envelope_body",
  "emailSubject":"envelope_subject",
  "compositeTemplates":[
    {
      "compositeTemplateId":"1",
      "serverTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"1",
          "templateId":"insert template id"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"2",
          "recipients":{
            "signers":[
                {
                    "clientUserId":"1234",
                    "email":"myemail",
                    "name":"applicant",
                    "recipientId":"1",
                    "roleName":"Applicant"
                }
                
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "compositeTemplateId":"1",
        "inlineTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"3",
          "documents":[
            {
              "documentBase64": " - insert base64 here",
              "documentId":"10",
              "fileExtension":"PDF",
              "name":"addendum",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm testing using postman btw

Comment: Give more information about your question. Show your own procedure , what far you've done. **Don't put specific information in comment instead of the question, edit the question.**

 For further information, see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The request that you have above is using a server-side template (which contains a document) but you are also specifying a document in the request (the base64-encoded content).  The result will be two documents in your envelope.

You should remove the second composite template block if you do not want that document to be included.  E.g.

```
{
  "status":"sent",
  "emailBlurb":"envelope_body",
  "emailSubject":"envelope_subject",
  "compositeTemplates":[
    {
      "compositeTemplateId":"1",
      "serverTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"1",
          "templateId":"insert template id"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"2",
          "recipients":{
            "signers":[
              {
                "clientUserId":"1234",
                "email":"myemail",
                "name":"applicant",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "roleName":"Applicant"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you instead want to apply your server-side template to the document in your request, then these must be part of the same compositeTemplate block.  E.g. something like this:

```
{
  "status":"sent",
  "emailBlurb":"envelope_body",
  "emailSubject":"envelope_subject",
  "compositeTemplates":[
    {
      "compositeTemplateId":"1",
      "serverTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"1",
          "templateId":"insert template id"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates":[
        {
          "sequence":"2",
          "recipients":{
            "signers":[
              {
                "clientUserId":"1234",
                "email":"myemail",
                "name":"applicant",
                "recipientId":"1",
                "roleName":"Applicant"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": " - insert base64 here",
        "documentId":"10",
        "fileExtension":"PDF",
        "name":"addendum",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this way, the document overwrites the template, sending only the template.
how to send both?